# Response.Write() orchard

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I've created EventHandler, that call my service when user logged in with Orchard. Then I need to send js script with token. I tried to use httpContext.Response.Write(), but it didn't work in my EventHandler( I'm
beginner in Orchard and web api, so i need some help.

```
public class LoginUserEventHandler : IUserEventHandler {
    private readonly IAuthService _authService;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public LoginUserEventHandler(IAuthService authService, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
        _authService = authService;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Creating(UserContext context) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Created(UserContext context) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void LoggingIn(string userNameOrEmail, string password) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void LoggedIn(IUser user) {
       var token = _authService.GenerateLocalAccessTokenResponse(user.UserName);
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.Current();
        httpContext.Response.Write(token);
    }
```

UPDATE:
I need to send token in JQuery string, something like that:

```
var tokenKey = "tokenInfo";
sessionStorage.setItem(tokenKey, data.access_token);
```

Comment: I don't think you can "send js script". Please explain your use-case, I think you might be taking the wrong approach here

Comment: I need send token in javaScript code, that will save token on client

Comment: You should never use Response.Write in Orchard. Orchard is based on ASP.NET MVC, where you return an action result from a controller. In this particular case, it looks like you need to create a controller. I have no idea why you're trying to generate a token from a LoggedIn event. That's sure to mess up any normal attempt to log into the site. Also, there are probably modules on the gallery that already do exactly what you're trying to do. If you're an Orchard beginner, I'd recommend starting with something easier.

Comment: Whatever your goal is, perhaps you can use a cookie for this? Have a look at `FormsAuthenticationService`, here you will find the use of `IHttpContextAccessor` in connection with `Response` and cookies.

Comment: Yes, I'm an Orchard beginner. I have a module with my web api and I need to send to client access_token, when user loggin in. What modules in gallery do what I need?